# Slick Carousel unable to initialize method

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have several instances of the Slick Carousel gallery set up and working properly. However, I cannot successfully call the Methods as described in the documentation.
Whenever I try to execute a method after initialization is complete,the method did not perform. I'm trying to automatically goto the first slide after the slick is initiated.(the mothod "onInit " and "onReInit " is not perform.)

this is my code:

```
$("body #slick").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    centerPadding: "20px",
    draggable:false,
    onInit:function(){
      console.log("onInit");
      $("body #slick").slick("slickGoTo",0);
    },
    onReInit:function(){
      console.log("onReInit");
      $("body #slick").slick("slickGoTo",0);
    }
  });
```

thanks for help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the release notes [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/releases/tag/1.4.0):

> All callback methods are now deprecated. They have been replaced with event triggers. I added a few helpful ones too. So onAfterChange is now:

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

So, in your case:

```
$("body #slick").on('init', function() {
    console.log("onInit");
    $("body #slick").slick("slickGoTo",0);
});

$("body #slick").on('reInit', function() {
    console.log("onReInit");
    $("body #slick").slick("slickGoTo",0);
});

$("body #slick").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    centerPadding: "20px",
    draggable:false
});
```

Please note that all event handlers should be declared **before** calling `slick({...})`.

Comment: No problem, @dawn.
If my answer helped you, please consider marking my answer as the accepted one.
For more info, please visit this section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Thanks!